# Mollifiers: Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

Can you give me a hint how to check uniform convergence here:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}):\quad\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{1}{h}\left\{\varphi(t+h)-\varphi(t) \right\}-\varphi'(t)\right|\stackrel{h\to0}{\to}0$$
Pointwise is clear to me. Intuitively, this also makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
     \frac{\varphi(t+h)-\varphi(t)}{h} - \varphi'(t) = \frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{h}\{ \varphi'(t+s)-\varphi'(t)\}\,ds
$$

Comment: Aaah and I know that the derivative is continuous with compact support so uniformly continuous. Hehe. Thanks T.A.E.! :)